# Using a while loop to print random numbers until a certain number is reached

Tags: javascript, while-loop

How to use a while loop to generate random numbers until a certain number is reached? Help please

Comment: You should at least try something before you come ask for help.

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: Which part of this do you need help with?  Generating random numbers?  Making a `while` loop?  Checking if you've hit the number you want?

Answer (score 1):

Considering there is a random number generator `random` you will just do as shown below

```
do
{
   x=Math.random();
   x=x*range;
   if(x is desired number )
        break;  
   else
   {
         print the number.
   }     
}while(1)
print -( desired number found).
```

NOTE: As you are beginner you can try the following when designing these codes..

> 1. First find what is the input and what is the output.
> 2. Then try to draw a flow chart of the whole thing ( You can try running it yourself as if you are the computer)
> 3. Then all the branch and loop are converted to `if-else` or `for-while` loop.
> 4. Check the code and match input and output.

This is a basic program structure..Instead of asking in forums about common structures try reading some books.

**Hint 1:** There is a function in javascript called Math.random() return a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive):

**Hint 2:** check whether the values are equal. Use `===` in javascript.

**Hint 3:** check for `if else`, `break` and `do while`, `while` loop.

**Hint 4:** If you are given a random number `0<=x<1` then how do you generate a random number using in range `[a,b)` using the abobe geerated number? Ans: Use `b*x`.

hope this helps.

Comment: @apple tree.: Check my answer..try on your own a little bit..learn the key elements and you will surely benefit from it.

Comment: @apple tree.: If this helps please upvote/select the answer.

Comment: @Jesse.: Would you please check my answer..

Comment: @ skypjack.: Please check my answer..and tell me if anything needs to be changed.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat.: Please check my answer..and tell me if anything needs to be changed

Answer (score 1):

This code will generate integer numbers from 1 until 50.

```js
var number = 50;
var x = 0;
while(x !== number){
  x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
  console.log(x);
}
```